# What are Trampolines in assembly browser of DLL

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-binding

I have binded a static `Objective-C` library with `Xamarin`. I have a memory leak (an instance created from a library class does not get released) and I was diving in the Assembly Browser. I saw that the DLL essentially has three groups of resources:

- ApiDefinitions
- LibraryName
- ObjCRuntime

Under `ObjCRuntime` there is a subgroup named `Trampolines` which contains three types of resources:

- DActionArity1V0
- NIDActionArity1V0
- SDActionArity1V0

There are many of this resources with only the final two numbers different.

Just wanted to know how this bridging mechanism worked for `Objective-C` `block` callbacks.

Comment: Type "trampoline" in the search box.  If 1107 posts don't help then one more isn't that likely to be more useful.

Comment: Thank you, if you could use the link of one of them, which is relevant to the question, in the comment would be more useful.